# Select rows where date is not past 2 days and group by an attribute

Tags: mysql

I have a table with an integer attribute A and a date attribute B where there can be multiple rows for the same value

I am trying to select rows where value of column A = 'X' and none of the rows with column A = 'X' have a date equal to today

This is my current select statement:

```
select * 
from table
where DATE(B) != DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 0 DAY) 
and A = 'X'
group by A
order by B
```

However if there are two rows for column A = 'X' and at least one of them has a date value B equal to todays date, it returns that row.

Is there a way to select rows where none of the records for A = 'X' have been created today (B != today's date)?

Comment: What datatype is column `B`

Comment: A: int
B: date (YYYY-MM-DD)